# Having trouble with the brackets using /summon command, can someone please help?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on a map with my friend and I recently stumbled into a problem, neither me nor my friend know which brackets to change in this command:

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {    
HandItems:[    
{Count:1,id:iron_hoe,tag:
{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Scythe"},    
ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:19,lvl:2}]}},
{Count:1,id:book,
tag:{display:{Name:Magical Book}}}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:leather_boots,
tag:{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Weak Boots"}}},{Count:1,id:leather_leggings,
tag:{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Weak Pants"}}},{Count:1,id:leather_chestplate,
tag:{display:{color:3157807,
tag:{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Weak Tunic"}}}},{Count:1,id:skull,Damage:3,
tag:{SkullOwner:Grimreaper}}],CustomName:Grim Reaper,Visible:1,HandDropChances:[0.2f,0.1f]}
```

I am fairly sure it has to do with the tag to color the chestplate.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It says unbalanced brackets

Answer (score 0):

I have balanced your brackets on line 9 and 12. Please try this code:

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {    
HandItems:[    
{Count:1,id:iron_hoe,tag:
{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Scythe"},    
ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:19,lvl:2}]}},
{Count:1,id:book,
tag:{display:{Name:Magical Book}}}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:leather_boots,
tag:{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Weak Boots"}}},{Count:1,id:leather_leggings,
tag:{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Weak Pants"}}},{Count:1,id:leather_chestplate,
tag:{display:{color:3157807,
tag:{display:{Name:"Grim Reaper's Weak Tunic"}}}}},{Count:1,id:skull,Damage:3,
tag:{SkullOwner:Grimreaper}}],CustomName:Grim Reaper,Visible:1,HandDropChances:[0.2f,0.1f]}
```